# What does 5 equal in $Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question I am trying to solve is show that 5 is not irreducible in $Z[i]$.  In order to solve this I need to show what makes up five, and then show neither of the two elements is a unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5=5+0i$$
$$=(2+i)(2-i)$$
Now show that none of $2+i$ and $2-i$ is a unit.

Comment: N(2+i)=5 which does not equal 1 so it's not a unit same thing for (2-i).  Is that correct?

Comment: What is N(x)? To show that something is not a unit, you need to assume a multiplicative inverse of that and then get a contradiction.

Comment: @Martund Presumably that's the field norm $N: \mathbb{Q}(i) \to \mathbb{Q}, a + bi \mapsto a^2 + b^2$. And yes, user710744, your reasoning is correct. Well, technically you should argue that the norm is not $-1$ either, but that's clear in this case.